# How do I use the result of a callback and pass that result to the next callback?

Tags: javascript, function, callback

So my function accepts a value and any number of callbacks as
arguments (should I use the spread operator?). The function should return the final result of passing the value through all of the given callbacks.

```
let chainMap = function(num, cb1, cb2, cb3) {
    if(cb2 === undefined && cb3 === undefined){
       let res1 = cb1(num);
        return res1;
    } else if(cb3 === undefined){
       let res2 = cb2(res1);
        return res2;
    } else {
        let res3 = cb3(res2);
        return res3;
    }

  };

let add5 = function(n) {
    return n + 5;
};

let half = function(n) {
    return n / 2;
};

let square = function(n) {
    return n * n;
};

console.log(chainMap(25, add5));                // 30
console.log(chainMap(25, add5, half));          // 15
console.log(chainMap(25, add5, half, square));  // 225
console.log(chainMap(4, square, half));         // 8
console.log(chainMap(4, half, square));         // 4
```

I am returning "cb2(res1)" is not a function. How do I pass the results of my first callback to the next callback?

Comment: You need to check whether the callback function parameters are `undefined` **before** you try to call them.

Comment: Do you know `Array.reduce`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce. `let chainMap = function(num, cbs) {  return cbs.reduce((a, cb) => cb(a), num); }`

Comment: `cb2 && cb3 === undefined)` <-- This doesn't do what you think it does. First, `cb2` is checked for a truthy value, then (if so) `cb3` is checked to see if it is exactly `undefined`. If you want to check both for `undefined`, you'd write `cb2 === undefined && cb3 === undefined)`

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. I'm still returning cb2 is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

res1 is declared as a local variable in this scope, you can´t use it outside the scope.

```
    if(cb2 === undefined && cb3 === undefined){
       let res1 = cb1(num);
       return res1;
    }
```

Also, you can´t "chain" with and if/else statement.
Here´s an example code of what you are trying to do:

```js
let chainMap = function(num, cb1, cb2, cb3) {
  let temp = 0;
    if(cb1){
       temp = cb1(num);
    } 
    if(cb2){
       temp = cb2(temp)
    } 
    if(cb3){
        temp = cb3(temp);
    }
  return temp
};
let add5 = function(n) {
    return n + 5;
};

let half = function(n) {
    return n / 2;
};

let square = function(n) {
    return n * n;
};
console.log(chainMap(25, add5));                // 30
console.log(chainMap(25, add5, half));           // 15
console.log(chainMap(25, add5, half, square));  // 225
console.log(chainMap(4, square, half));         // 8
console.log(chainMap(4, half, square));         // 4
```

Another way:

```js
let chainMap = function(num, cb1, cb2, cb3) {
    if(cb2 === undefined && cb3 === undefined){
       let res1 = cb1(num);
        return res1;
    } else if(cb3 === undefined){
       let res2 = cb2(cb1(num));
        return res2;
    } else {
        let res3 = cb3(cb2(cb1(num)));
        return res3
    }

  };
let add5 = function(n) {
    return n + 5;
};

let half = function(n) {
    return n / 2;
};

let square = function(n) {
    return n * n;
};
console.log(chainMap(25, add5));                // 30
console.log(chainMap(25, add5, half));           // 15
console.log(chainMap(25, add5, half, square));  // 225
console.log(chainMap(4, square, half));         // 8
console.log(chainMap(4, half, square));         // 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be the use of rest parameter syntax in the case of undetermined amount of callback functions:

```
let chainMap = function(num, ...callbacks) {
  let result = num;
  if(callbacks === undefined) {
    return result;
  } else {
    callbacks.forEach(element => {
      result = element(result);
    });
    return result;
  }

};

let add5 = function(n) {
  return n + 5;
};

let half = function(n) {
  return n / 2;
};

let square = function(n) {
  return n * n;
};

console.log(chainMap(25, add5));                // 30
console.log(chainMap(25, add5, half));          // 15
console.log(chainMap(25, add5, half, square));  // 225
console.log(chainMap(4, square, half));         // 8
console.log(chainMap(4, half, square));         // 4
```